# Can't write on NFC Tag after reading with Google's web NFC sample

Tags: authentication, nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I have a NFC Tag Mifare Classic 1k which I was using with NFC Tools for android, and stopped being able to write after reading with web NFC sample (see: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/).

After troubleshoothing and trying to format with MiFare Classic Tool the app shows this error with all blocks:

Key with write access (B) not known

This is the dump file:

```
+Sector: 0
9C441114DD0804000330A941C9310E1D
140103E103E103E103E103E103E103E1
03E103E103E103E103E103E103E103E1
A0A1A2A3A4A5787788C1FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 1
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 2
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 3
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 4
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 5
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 6
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 7
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 8
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 9
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 10
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 11
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 12
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 13
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 14
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
+Sector: 15
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
D3F7D3F7D3F77F078840FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I'm new to NFC and I'm not sure if it's corrupted or what happened and I don't make the same mistake.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it has been formatted in the proprietary way to store NDEF data as per the doc https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf

Which implementations of Web NFC might optionally support (as the web NFC standard allows support of non NFC Forum standard formats).

I don't think it is corrupted but not all hardware and software supports this proprietary Tag configuration.

I would try using the TagInfo and TagWriter Apps by NXP as these are written by the makers of the Tag and TagWriter has a factory reset erase method.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the erase to factory default option with NPX app, but the result was "This tag can't be erased (Parts of) Tag protected" and when reading the tag it asks me to format it, should I erase & format as NDEF?